# ASP MVC [ForeignKey] trouble with type property in old DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with [ForeignKey] in an ASP MVC project.

Code from model:

```
public partial class drugs
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    [Required]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    [Required]
    public string jm { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    [Required]
    public string portion { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public double? portionJM { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string pkwiu { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Vat")]
    public int? vat { get; set; }

    public short? firmId { get; set; }

    public short? type { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("firmId")]
    [Display(Name = "Gatunek")]
    public virtual  maker maker { get; set; }
}
```

and the second model:

```
public partial class maker
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string NIP { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string city { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string postalCode { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    public string adress { get; set; }

    [StringLength(15)]
    public string phone { get; set; }
}
```

this code throw exception :

> The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential
>   constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the
>   Principal Role. The type of property 'firmId' on entity 'drugs' does
>   not match the type of property 'id' on entity 'maker' in the
>   referential constraint 'drugs_maker'.

I tried to solve the problem by changing "firmid" type from short? to int? in the first model but then I got this exception:

> The 'firmId' property on 'drugs' could not be set to a 'System.Int16'
>   value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type
>   'System.Int32'.

I can't change the property type in the DB, because this is an old DB working with a windowsforms application and I haven't got access to the code of this application. The solution to this problem must happen in my ASP MVC project.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: If the database already exists, you could try a [reverse engineer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620(v=vs.113).aspx) on those 2 tables to see what EF suggests.

Comment: `public short? firmId` wait, why the `maker` model had `int` instead of `short`? the limit is noticable and i think it causes your issue, try to change the `short` with `int` -- theoretically should be safe as you convert shorter binary to longer one not the reverse.